# SELECT query using collate binary_ci with arg mapped to multiple params

Tags: spring-data-jpa, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to create a spring data jpa custom query that takes 2 args and uses `collate binary_ci`. One arg is compared to a string using '=', the other is compared to a string using LIKE.
Example that works *without* `collate binary_ci`:

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID = :id AND ((MODEL LIKE %:in%) OR (DESCR LIKE %:in%)) ORDER BY ...
```

The LIKE arg `in` is mapped to multiple parameters. I cannot get this query to work. I have tried multiple things, but in the end, my attempt to include `collate binary_ci` is the issue. Here is what I've tried:

```
    WHERE ID = :id AND ((MODEL LIKE %:in%) OR (DESCR LIKE %:in%)) collate binary_ci ORDER BY ...
    WHERE ID = :id AND (MODEL LIKE %:in% OR DESCR LIKE %:in%) collate binary_ci ORDER BY ...
    WHERE ID = :id AND ((MODEL LIKE %:in%) collate binary_ci OR (DESCR LIKE %:in%) collate binary_ci) ORDER BY
```

Running these queries gets me either `Could not locate named parameter [in], expecting one of [in%, id]` or `sql statement was not ended properly` or `missing right parentheses`

How can I make this work?

Version:  `Spring-Boot:  (v2.4.3)`

Here are version values from my sqldeveloper:

```
org.openide.specification.version   6.2
org.osgi.framework.os.version   10.0.0
org.osgi.framework.version  1.7.0
os.version  10.0
osgi.framework.version  3.9.1.v20140110-1610
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
WHERE ID = :id AND ((MODEL LIKE %:in% collate binary_ci) OR (DESCR LIKE %:in% collate binary_ci)) ORDER BY...
```